# Moon phase data for Queensland, Australia

Tags: data-request, data.gov, uses-of-open-data

I am looking for a moon phase calendar for Queensland, Australia. Something which might have dates and moon phase on a particular date. Any ideas where can I find such a complete calendar for say last 25 years?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moon phase data is usually computed, not observed. Additionally, moon phase data is not location dependent. The full moon occurs at the same time for all locations: http://www.lunarabundance.com/full-moon-same-time-around-the-world/

http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/13488/where-can-i-find-visualize-planets-stars-moons-etc-positions may be helpful in finding moon phases, though google should also be helpful.

If you believe the computed moon phase data may be inaccurate and want to compare it to observed moon phases, you might poke around on astrophotography sites.